# (REACT) Optimising API call chain causes components to not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, use-effect

this is my first ever post to here so apologies in advance for any faux pas's.

So I'm building a web-app that requires a series of API calls to populate search queries the user makes. However the data received from the initial API call (one corresponding to the search terms passed to the site) is incomplete for the purposes of the app. Hence I collate all of the ids together into an array which is then looped over for the second API call to get the complete data. The following is all in my App.js

```
// tags are the search terms the user inputs 
const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
// searchResults is the complete data retrieved from the API call
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
//for loading screen 
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

```
 useEffect(() => {

        // apiSearchCall contains the incomplete data 

        apiSearchCall(tags).then((data) => {
            if (data.drinks === "None Found") {
                setNoDrinks(true);
            } else {
                let idArr = aggregateID(data);
                let drinks = [];
                idArr.forEach((element) => {
                    // apiIndividualCall contains the complete data
                    apiIndividualCall(element).then((dataFinal) => {
                        drinks.push(dataFinal.drinks[0]);
                        setSearchResults({ drinks });
                    });
                });
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });
    }, [setSearchResults, setLoading, tags]);
```

searchResults is then sent to another component `Card.js`

While this does give me the functionality I do need([Here is a video demonstrating it](https://i.imgur.com/DyVHlwk.mp4)), it comes at a hefty performance hit as the searchResults are reset on every iteration of the forEach loop and *I think* each component is re-rendered. In an attempt to optimise this, I have tried the following separately

- Lifted the pre-allocation of drinks to outside of the `.then()` and called `setSearchResults` and `setLoading` outside of the `.then()`
- removed `setLoading` and `setSearchResults` and added them another chained `.then()`
- removed the forEach loop and added it to a seperate helper function which returns what would've been the contents of drinks and passed that to `setSearchResults`

**All** of these attempts have resulted in [the components not rendering](https://i.imgur.com/zKgiqOp.mp4). After console.log-ing a lot of my code I discovered the **right information is being passed to the card component** and all the logic runs up-until we hit the return statement where nothing is run from there on.

My gut feeling is that I might be missing something fundamental about how `useEffect()` works, but I am not sure what it might be

If it would help at all I am utilising this API

https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php

Where the results of the search for ingredients (`apiSearchCall()` in my code) has the following structure

```
{
"drinks": [
    {
      "strDrink": "Chocolate Beverage",
      "strDrinkThumb": "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/jbqrhv1487603186.jpg",
      "idDrink": "12732"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting the initial state of searchResults to an array, but when you later call setSearchResults you are passing an object?

Comment: @Chris Good catch, layover from when I was gonna have searchResults as an array but changed it later down the track

Comment: My initial thoughts when looking at this are that I think you are pretty much there - but every time you set the state, you are passing the same array. By that, I mean that although the contents of the drinks array may have changed, it’s still the same array. React doesn’t look at the contents of the array, it just looks at the reference to the array. You might find that if you spread the array (I.e create a new array) each time, that will trigger the rendering - setSearchResults({drinks: [...drinks]})